# How to deploy a C# library that uses C++/CLI libraries

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I have a C# library that builds using AnyCPU but has dependencies on a few C++/CLI libraries. I have compiled the C++/CLI for both x86 and x64 Windows. It seems like I am only able to add a single reference of the C++/CLI library to the C# project (otherwise the files over write each other). I thought it would be possible to have a x86 and x64 folder that the respective libraries would live in. But when I tried this I would get runtime exceptions about not being able to find the library.

Is there any way to include both the x86 and x64 with my AnyCpu library so that when it is deployed the calling application can decide if they want x86 or x64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basically you need to do the following:**

- detect process architecture (x86 or x64)
- load the right library according the architecture

**Get the path of the library to load according process architecture:**

```
    public NativeLibraryLoader(string path32, string path64)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path32))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("32-bit library not found.", path32);

        if (!File.Exists(path64))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("64-bit library not found.", path64);

        string path;

        switch (RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture)
        {
            case Architecture.X86:
                path = path32;
                break;
            case Architecture.X64:
                path = path64;
                break;
            default:
                throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
        }

        ...
    }
```

**Load the native library with `LoadLibrary`:**

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lpLibFileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibrary", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);
```

**Complete example:**

You can check out [aubio.net](https://github.com/aybe/aubio.net), a .NET wrapper I've written for [aubio](https://github.com/aubio/aubio). It's an `AnyCPU` assembly that will load either the `x86` or the `x64` library according the current architecture it is running on.

These are the bits you'll be interested by:

https://github.com/aybe/aubio.net/tree/master/Aubio/Interop

https://github.com/aybe/aubio.net/blob/master/Aubio/AubioNative.cs

**Caveat:**

This method explains how to load a **native** library and not a managed one.

As **@Flydog57** pointed out, to load a managed assembly use `Assembly.Load` instead.

Comment: @165plo: Actually, if the C++/CLI DLL is a managed assembly (which is how I read the question), then you will want to use `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load` or one of its friends.  But, the logic holds true.  It doesn't help you from a "referenced assembly" point of view though.  If you have control over the C++/CLI code, have the classes implement interfaces you define in a common AnyCPU assembly that both your code and the C++/CLI code reference

Comment: Is there not a native way of doing this? I find it kind of wierd that it's not part of the native library discovery.

Comment: What do you mean by native way?

Comment: The solution above gets called at method invocation, correct? I am supprised that the IL Interpreter doesn't offer a way to do this at application launch. I could be wrong, but I thought all dlls we're loaded at applications start.

Comment: Yes but as you've pointed out, you can only add a single reference to an assembly, there is no differentiation as on what architecture it's for, i.e. it expects you to add the right one for your project. Now it's not terribly difficult to implement,

Comment: It seems like a common enough requirement that I wouldn't expect to have to add specific code. I will implement it as you described above. Thanks!